# Add index in EF Model First design

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I like the option of doing model first design with the Entity Framework (4). However, I haven't been able to find out how to add an additional index to a table besides the primary key.

Is this possible in the visual designer? Or do you need to add an index manually after creating the database (which would be a shortcoming of the designer)?

Comment: Read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362.aspx). Section **Influencing the DDL Generation**. HTH