# Specify Index Column in EF Model-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

How to define a property as index column, in EF Model-First?

Five years later when [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333674/add-index-in-ef-model-first-design) had been asked for EF-4.0. Do we still have to manually edit .edmx file to add index? I believe this is a pretty trivial scenario & there must be a better way, isn't it?

Comment: In 2020 in the edmx editor I still don't see any visual way to specify if a column would be unique or I would want to have an index on it. Very disappointing, this is such a basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't read the question properly. This applies only to Code First. OP asked about Model-First.

Starting with EF 6.1 you can use the `Index` attribute. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx for details like unique indexes and multicolumn indexes.